# Test naming - Resharper and xUnit

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper, bdd, xunit

In the R# 8.2.0 and VS2013.3, test runner I'd like to group by Traits, as in the VS test runner:

Question: Can I get R# showing tests like this:

[image]

In R# the closest I can get is this:

[image]

Test code is:

```
    [Trait("Homepage", "User changes sort order to highest rating first")]
public class ChangeSortOrderToRating : IntegrationTestBaseWithData {
    readonly JokeViewer viewer;
    public ChangeSortOrderToRating() {
        viewer = new JokeViewer(new Session());
    }

    [Fact(DisplayName = "Show all 3 Stories")]
    public void ShowAllStories() {
        List<Joke> result = viewer.ShowAllJokesHighestRatingFirst();
        Assert.Equal(3, result.Count);
    }
    [Fact(DisplayName = "Show all Stories in rating order")]
    public void ShowListOfStoriesInDescendingRankOrder() {
        var result = viewer.ShowAllJokesHighestRatingFirst();
        // 10,2,5 is order of insert in db
        // First should be rating of 2
        Assert.Equal(10, result[0].Rating);
        Assert.Equal(5, result[1].Rating);
        Assert.Equal(2, result[2].Rating);
    }
}
```

R# extension for xUnit installed:
[image]

Comment: What's the question? Looks like the ReSharper runner is showing the right tests grouped by category.

Comment: Have put in a more obvious question edit.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you'd like to avoid the method names in there, unfortunately, right now, that's not really possible.

The way the ReSharper plugin works with xunit 1.x means that the display name isn't available until a test is actually run (because the plugin is using xunit's API to locate tests, but the `DisplayName` property can't be invoked because it's looking at source code rather than compiled code. The `DisplayName` might be doing anything to the code (e.g. `Theory` attributes add parameter information), so there isn't a value to use when building the tests from code.

I'm hoping that xunit 2.x support will fix this. 2.x is taking great pains to make sure that all information can be retrieved based on source code analysis, so the xunit API can invoke a Reflection-like abstraction to get all the information, including a nice display name. The support for 2.x is currently in progress, with tests running nicely, but still using xunit 1.x to discover tests.

Comment: Thank you citizenmatt - I hope 2.x goes well!  I will endeavour to come back to this question if there are any updates in the future.

Comment: I've been looking for this as well - don't think it's possible yet though.